# How to stop cloning text entered inside <Td> element while using .clone() in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a request to create a table, with "dynamic" rows adding when TAB is being pressed on last column in a row.

Eventually I've created a structure in HTML

```
<table id="some_table">
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

And then I've used this simple code for JS

```
$('#some_table').on('keydown', 'input', function (e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode;
    if (keyCode !== 9) return;
    var $this = $(this),
        $lastTr = $('tr:last', $('#some_table')),
        $lastTd = $('td:last', $lastTr);
    if (($(e.target).closest('td')).is($lastTd)) {
        $lastTr.after($lastTr.clone());
    }
});
```

And I've added script source

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

What it actually does, when you type data and press TAB on last one, the clone() is cloning last row WITH DATA, and I want to avoid that. I would like to just clone the empty columns for a new row, in fact, create new row with same structure which does not have any data.

How can one do that?

I've added [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c92qswu8/2/) link to it

Comment: Check out [mustache](https://mustache.github.io) This is a template engine, you can define a base template and then just add it whenever you need it. Or is this not a possibility?

Comment: Sry I don't get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just added this to your code

```
    $('tr:last', $('#some_table')).find('td > input').each(function(index, value){
    $(value).val('')
  })
```

Take a look at
https://jsfiddle.net/ctxmb29q/

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much!